# php paypal sdk installation

Tags: php

i am installing th paypal sdk kit and getting an error

INSTALLATION ERROR: Missing required PHP extention(s) for WPS Toolkit: curl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you might not have CURL. Check your php.ini file and make sure this line is present

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Make sure there is no semicolon before it. Then restart Apache

**EDIT**

Create a new file and put it in your webroot. Put the following command in that file and load it

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
```

This will show all the modules that are loaded for your installation. Search for the section `curl`. If it doesn't show up then you're editing the wrong `php.ini`.

The `php.ini` path is listed at the top. Open that up and do the needful.

Comment: and there is no semicolon before it? Restart apache after any change you do

Comment: This installer will overwrite any existing files in the target directory. Continue (y or n)? this comes and nothing happens

Comment: If you plan to use the Encrypted Website Payments (EWP) functionality of the SDK, you will need to install the PHP OpenSSL Extention. 


how can i do this

Answer (score 2):

you have to enable CURL with php.

uncomment the line `;extension=php_curl.dll` in php.ini and restart apache

Comment: If you plan to use the Encrypted Website Payments (EWP) functionality of the SDK, you will need to install the PHP OpenSSL Extention. 


how to remove this error

Comment: Read the manual as @JohnP listed in his comment  http://www.php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php